# Running Zopim Chat after page load hurts page speed

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, zendesk, zopim

I have integrated Zendesk Zopim Chat to Vuestore front. Though adding this chat causes the pagespeed to drop score.

I did added the script through async and added this code in `mounted` section of page

```
      zE(() => {
        // Zopim API
        $zopim(() => {
          $zopim.livechat.concierge.setTitle('SiteTitle');
          $zopim.livechat.concierge.setName('Name');
          $zopim.livechat.concierge.setAvatar('https://example.com/siteLogo.svg');
          $zopim.livechat.window.setTitle('Support');
          $zopim.livechat.prechatForm.setGreetings('How can we help?');
          $zopim.livechat.theme.reload();
        });
      });
```

Now the issue is that it's affecting the page speed.

I have added screenshot that how it is affecting the page speed.

[image]

Check this below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `Lacks clarity | Difficult to mentally parse | Home-made title tags`

Comment: Please also include how you're loading the Zendesk Snippet